# Getting time of logs stored in ASL log files with ASL API -Objective C

Tags: objective-c

As we know , we can use ASL (Apple System Logger) API in objective C to read logs and also with using asl_search it is possible to retrieve specific application logs. 
But the problem is output of asl does not include the time when the log was created. 
For example , when you open system.log in directory /var/log with Apple System Logger ,you see logs like this :

> **Nov 28 09:19:37 localhost bootlog[0]: BOOT_TIME 1354123177 0**

But when quering asl with objective C , it reports every attribute of log except the time when the log is created, it means in example mentioned above , asl_search does not report Nov 28 09:19:37
Is there anyway to include time of creating logs with quering asl in objective C?
If this is not possible , what is another approach to retrieving time of logs?

---

This is my code , note that the time of logs which we can see in system.log files in /var/log does not appear in output of my code .

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

```
NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
aslmsg q, m;
int i;
const char *key, *val;
q = asl_new(ASL_TYPE_QUERY);
asl_set_query(q, ASL_KEY_SENDER, "bootlog", ASL_QUERY_OP_EQUAL);

aslresponse r = asl_search(NULL, q);

while (NULL != (m = aslresponse_next(r)))
{
    NSMutableDictionary *tmpDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    for (i = 0; (NULL != (key = asl_key(m, i))); i++)
    {
        NSString *keyString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)key];

        val = asl_get(m, key);

        NSString *string = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:val];
        [tmpDict setObject:string forKey:keyString];
    }

    NSLog(@"%@", tmpDict);

}
aslresponse_free(r);

[pool drain];
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Did you have a chance to check my answer? If it helped, you can "accept" it by clicking on the check mark to the left of the answer. Otherwise feel free to ask for details.

Comment: Hi.Your answer is absolutely right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The timestamp of the log message is the value of the `ASL_KEY_TIME` key in the message. The value is a UNIX time (seconds since 1.1.1970).

You can convert the timestamp of the log message to `NSDate` with

```
NSDate *time = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:(strtod(asl_get(m, ASL_KEY_TIME), NULL))];
```

Comment: Thank you so much Mr.Martin R

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Swift, there's a new open-source project called [CleanroomASL](https://github.com/emaloney/CleanroomASL) that provides a type-safe API for reading and writing Apple System Log entries.

Querying the log returns the timestamp for each entry:

```
let client = ASLClient()
let query = ASLQueryObject()

client.search(query) { record in
    if let record = record {
        // we've gotten a log entry for the search.
        // 'record' is of type ASLQueryObject.ResultRecord;
        // you can access the timestamp as an NSDate
        // using the record.timestamp property
    }
    else {
        // there are no more log entries to process
    }
    // return true while we still want to get results
    // or return false when we don't want to process more
    return true
}
```

You can constrain your search query by setting additional query keys:

```
query.setQueryKey(.Message, value: nil, operation: .KeyExists, modifiers: .None)
query.setQueryKey(.Time, value: Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 - (60 * 60)), operation: .GreaterThanOrEqualTo, modifiers: .None)
```

The code above would return all ASL log entries recorded in the last 5 minutes that also have a value for the `.Message` attribute.

**Note:** On an iOS device, ASL will *only* return log entries made by your process. Also, logs are pruned rather aggressively, and may only include entries made by the current run of your application. If you want to persist your log entries beyond that, you may want to look into a more robust Swift logging package such as [CleanroomLogger](https://github.com/emaloney/CleanroomLogger).

The differences between ASL behavior on the Mac/iOS Simulator and on an iOS device are explained further in the section *Differences between the device and simulator* on the CleanroomASL project page on GitHub.